# Parse nested HTML for Links and Info

Tags: javascript, php, html, parsing, simple-html-dom

I am trying to parse a website (files.minecraftforge.net) and grab both the download links as well as information such as the version and build time for each one. I am using the Simple HTML DOM Parser and its been working great thus far, however I have been tinkering with the documentation and can't fully understand it.

Each table row has 5 TDs. I need to grab the data from the first 4 (Promotion, Version, Minecraft, Time) as well as the data I am already collecting from the URLs. The following code works to grab the URL and title (innertext) but how do I also grab the td information for the row as well?

I think the best approach would be to use foreach() to grab the rows, then do a foreach inside of that for each td inside that TR. I unfortunately can't figure out how to run a foreach on what is returned from html->find();

```
foreach($html->find('table#promotions_table a') as $e)
{
    echo $e->innertext . '<br>';
    echo $e->href . '<br>';
}
```

A snippet of the HTML that I am trying to parse appears as so...

```
  <table border="0" id="promotions_table">
    <tr>
      <th>Promotion</th>
      <th>Version</th>
      <th>Minecraft</th>
      <th>Time</th>
      <th>Downloads</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1.6.4-Latest</td>
      <td>9.11.1.965</td>
      <td>1.6.4</td>
      <td>11/21/2013 02:31:00 PM</td>
       <td>
      (<a href="http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.6.4-9.11.1.965/forge-1.6.4-9.11.1.965-changelog.txt">Changelog</a>)
      (<a href="http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.6.4-9.11.1.965/forge-1.6.4-9.11.1.965-installer.jar">Installer</a>)
      <a href="http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.6.4-9.11.1.965/forge-1.6.4-9.11.1.965-installer.jar">*</a>
      (<a href="http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.6.4-9.11.1.965/forge-1.6.4-9.11.1.965-javadoc.zip">Javadoc</a>)
      <a href="http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.6.4-9.11.1.965/forge-1.6.4-9.11.1.965-javadoc.zip">*</a>
      (<a href="http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.6.4-9.11.1.965/forge-1.6.4-9.11.1.965-src.zip">Src</a>)
      <a href="http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.6.4-9.11.1.965/forge-1.6.4-9.11.1.965-src.zip">*</a>
      (<a href="http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.6.4-9.11.1.965/forge-1.6.4-9.11.1.965-universal.jar">Universal</a>)
      <a href="http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.6.4-9.11.1.965/forge-1.6.4-9.11.1.965-universal.jar">*</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1.6.4-Recommended</td>
      <td>9.11.1.965</td>
      <td>1.6.4</td>
      <td>11/21/2013 02:31:00 PM</td>
       <td>
      (<a href="http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.6.4-9.11.1.965/forge-1.6.4-9.11.1.965-changelog.txt">Changelog</a>)
      (<a href="http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.6.4-9.11.1.965/forge-1.6.4-9.11.1.965-installer.jar">Installer</a>)
      <a href="http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.6.4-9.11.1.965/forge-1.6.4-9.11.1.965-installer.jar">*</a>
      (<a href="http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.6.4-9.11.1.965/forge-1.6.4-9.11.1.965-javadoc.zip">Javadoc</a>)
      <a href="http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.6.4-9.11.1.965/forge-1.6.4-9.11.1.965-javadoc.zip">*</a>
      (<a href="http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.6.4-9.11.1.965/forge-1.6.4-9.11.1.965-src.zip">Src</a>)
      <a href="http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.6.4-9.11.1.965/forge-1.6.4-9.11.1.965-src.zip">*</a>
      (<a href="http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.6.4-9.11.1.965/forge-1.6.4-9.11.1.965-universal.jar">Universal</a>)
      <a href="http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.6.4-9.11.1.965/forge-1.6.4-9.11.1.965-universal.jar">*</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do so with further experimenting. Here is how I did it in case anyone else encounters the same question.

```
foreach($html->find('table#promotions_table tr') as $tr)
{
    $details = array();
    $count = 0;

    foreach ($tr->find('td') as $td)
    {
        switch ($count)
        {
            case 0:
            {
                $details['title'] = $td->innertext;
                echo "TITLE: " . $details['title'] . "</br>";
                break;
            }
            case 1:
            {
                $details['build'] = $td->innertext;
                echo "BUILD: " . $details['build'] . "</br>";
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                $details['version'] = $td->innertext;
                echo "VERSION: " . $details['version'] . "</br>";
                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                $details['time'] = $td->innertext;
                echo "TIME: " . $details['time'] . "</br>";
                break;
            }
            case 4:
            {
                foreach ($td->find('a') as $a)
                {
                    if ($a->innertext == "Installer")
                    {
                        $url = $a->href;

                        // Strip the "adf.ly" URL from the beginning of the text
                        preg_match("#https?://(www\.)?adf\.ly/\d+/(.*)#i", $url, $matches);
                        echo "URL: " . $matches[2] . "</br>";

                        $details['url'] = $a->href;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was going to suggest much the same thing.  You might be able to simplify a little, instead of the switch you could do `$details['title'] = $tr->find('td', 1)->innerText;` where 1 is the nth-child index of the td in question.  But yes, good solution :)